# Angular after deployment not using new hashed files

Tags: javascript, angular, caching, deployment

Whenever I deploy my angular application(with output hashing all) option, my browser can't get new hashed js files. It still points to old one.

I restarted site on iis, it pulls new files. But when browser restarts it again points back to old js files.

This is my build configuration.

```
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": true,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
```

Can someone point me to right direction?

This is quite frustrating because after deployments I have to ask my customers to clear cache.

Comment: Probably because your browser cached the html for the page itself. So your old versison of the page still points to the old hashes

Comment: What is the solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing resolved this issue was to clear cache from user's browser and then enabling cache with Expire web content immediately setting on IIS.

More details on cache setting in iis here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to turn off cache for every file type on the clients, you just need to turn it off for the index.html.
In nginx it is something like this:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(?:css|cur|js|jpe?g|gif|htc|ico|png|xml|otf|ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header X-debug-other-files 2;
    
    tcp_nodelay off;
    open_file_cache max=3000 inactive=120s;
    open_file_cache_valid 45s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors off;
}

location / {
    add_header X-debug-root 1;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri @index;
}

location @index {
    add_header X-debug-index 2;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    expires 0;
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
```

debug headers will help you to understand which directive is affecting the files.